# Can I somehow change my character's appearance in GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I was making my character on GTA V Online (Xbox) & totally didn't realize I messed up and me being the perfectionist I am, I've been trying to change it for the past hour. Some sites on Google say it's impossible, but others say it is, and I've even seen Rockstar give a one-time ticket to change their appearance. Could anyone provide further help, or even help me get a ticket to change my appearance? Thank you!!!

Comment: RStar should add plastic surgery clinic ;)

Comment: But cant you just make a new charechter? Is this one really important?

Comment: I mean, I guess, but I have played a little on this character & bought some clothes oblivious to the fact that I messed up on it.

Comment: And I agree, there should be a plastic surgery clinic

Comment: If it's a brand new character just make a new one, not worth the hassle

Comment: You can just get the free stuff with the new charechter. And the money will transfer between charechters depending whether theyre in your hand or bank

Answer (score 5):

With the Import/Export update Rockstar introduced the ability to change character appearance as many times as desired.

The option to do so is located in the interaction menu which can be accessed by pressing m on a keyboard or holding the back/select button on a controller. It will be under the sub-menu labeled style and cost 100,000 in-game.

Gender is not able to be changed but all other options present upon initial character creation are available.

Please note that since GTAV for PS3 and 360 is no longer receiving updates this option is unavailable on those platforms. In this case it might be possible for Rockstar support to reset appearance but I cannot find an example of this for last-gen copies.

References

- Patch notes for Import/Export https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/236222747
- Ticket showing R* support can initiate appearance reset https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204246987-Change-Character-appearance